# Bootstrap 3 dropdown select value

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a dropdown menu using `select` with a `value`/`options`.  How can I do this using Bootstrap?

```
<div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="type" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        Please Select
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="type">
        <li><a href="#">General User</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Service Provider</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Admin</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For form components such as `select` bootstrap use `.form-control`, see docs [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls) and see `select` docs example [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#selects)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<select class="form-control">
  <option value="General User">General User</option>
  <option value="Service Provider">Service Provider</option>
  <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
</select>
```